# React js : change css class based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to give a css class to div based on particular condition. It always takes the last condition.

Here is my code.

I get `logos.length` as 3

```html
<div className= "${ (this.state.logos && (this.state.logos.length == 3)) ? 'width_15_percent' : (this.state.logos && (this.state.logos.length == 2)) ? 'width_20_percent' : 'width_50_percent' } ">

some data

</div>
```

any help would be great.

thank you.

Comment: What is that $ character for? Try to remove that.

Comment: Your condition seems ok to me.

Comment: @SergeK.. still it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

```js
< div className = {
    (this.state.logos && (this.state.logos.length === 3)) ? 'width_15_percent' :
      (this.state.logos && (this.state.logos.length === 2)) ? 'width_20_percent' : 'width_50_percent'
  } >
  some data < /div>
```

Comment: whats not working, its working on my system I checked

Comment: you must be getting some error, on compile, what's that

Comment: it always takes last condition. as I have 3 logos so 1st condition should execute. but it always takes the 3rd condition which is width_50_percent

Comment: then its problem with you this.state.logos, the value is not coming properly, because its working fine on my machine

Comment: check what is returned in this.state.logos

Comment: put this code above div, and see what is printed on page {this.state.logos}{this.state.logos.length}

Comment: yes.. I have done that. I get error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: so where did you define logos in state, check that and fix that-

Comment: when I print `{this.state.logos}` , I get nothing in that.

Comment: where are you intializing logos?

Comment: I map it using map function. like this var logos =  this.props.comHBEventVal.imageLink.map(function(option, i){
        return (
          <li className={`navbar-li-div-li mobile-hide-logo ${this.state.navMobile} ${this.props.comHBEventVal.url? 'cursor-pointer' : ''}`} style={{height: 52}} key={i} onClick={()=>{this.props.comHBEventVal.url? window.open('http://' + this.props.comHBEventVal.url, '_blank') : null}}>
            <img src={option}  style={{height: 42}} />
          </li>
        )
    }.bind(this))

Comment: You have to use this.setState({logos:....logic.... goes here}), you cannot assign directly to logos, in react, also would you like to vote up my answer

Comment: I would definately do.. when I get 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The quotations and the $ symbols are not needed here. Pass your expression directly.

```
<div className={ (this.state.logos && (this.state.logos.length == 3)) ? 'width_15_percent' : (this.state.logos && (this.state.logos.length == 2)) ? 'width_20_percent' : 'width_50_percent' }>

some data

</div>
```

Comment: if i remove $ then i get whole syntax in the browser console

Comment: I'm sure you're returning the data -- return(...) .And what does the error say? Also your equality symbol should be === not ==, just a react recommendation though

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div className={ (this.state.logos && (this.state.logos.length == 3)) ? 'width_15_percent' : (this.state.logos && (this.state.logos.length == 2)) ? 'width_20_percent' : 'width_50_percent' }>

some data

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using String Literal ($) then you should replace " with `

```
<div className= `${ (this.state.logos && (this.state.logos.length == 
3)) ? 'width_15_percent' : (this.state.logos && 
(this.state.logos.length == 2)) ? 'width_20_percent' : 
'width_50_percent' }`>

some data

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion to use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) - its really simple but efficiently tool to joining classnames or set by condition

Answer (score 0):

There is a great Package for Managing classes check here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames/

Its is very easy to use like

First you have to install and then import like

```
import classNames from 'classnames'

<div className={classNames('yourClassName', { width_15_percent: this.state.logos.length == 3})}>
```

Will apply class "width_15_percent" your condition is true

Or If you dont want to use package then go like

```
<div className={`yourClassName ${(this.state.logos.length == 3) ? 'width_15_percent' : '' }`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readability create a method that will just return the correct class instead of writing all these double ternary operators. you could do something like this:

```
getClassName() {
  let width = null;

  switch (this.state.logos.length) {
    case 2:
      width = 20
      break;
    case 3:
      width = 15;
      break;
    default:
      width = 50;
      break;
  };

  return `width_${width}_percent`;
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className={this.getClassName()}>
  )
}
```